# Performing webservice XML request using SOAPUI to HTML/javascript

Tags: javascript, soapui

I am currently using SoapUI to invoke webservices using WSDL methods as advertised/exposed by an application. As an example of a request is below and have included a screenshot of the SoapUI. From the screenshot, you can see the URL of the webservice, the XML request and username. I would like to be able to invoke and send out the same request using javascript.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:com:ssn:schema:service:v2.1.1:JobManager.xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:GetJobResult>
         <urn:JobID>122164</urn:JobID>
      </urn:GetJobResult>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I would just need an example on how to do it, especially the part on how to send the username and password to the request.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsL50.png)

Comment: There are many examples on the internet if you do a little research - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758899/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-asmx-secure-by-basic-authentication-using-jqu

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to consume soap web service (.asmx) secure by basic authentication using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758899/how-to-consume-soap-web-service-asmx-secure-by-basic-authentication-using-jqu)